# C++ Template Specialization Doesn't Resolve in Some Cases

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am attempting to write a template specialization which serializes fields into a buffer. The below code MOSTLY works, although I am running into a weird problem when passing char pointer types to the code.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct ArgHandler;

// literal types
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct ArgHandler<T, Args...>
{
    static uint8_t* insert(uint8_t* buff, const T arg, const Args&... args)
    {   
        auto data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff); 
        *data = static_cast<T>(arg);
        return ArgHandler<Args...>::insert(buff + sizeof(T), args...);
    }   
};

// char ptr
template <typename... Args>
struct ArgHandler<const char*, Args...>
{
    // strings
    static uint8_t* insert(uint8_t* buff, const char* arg, const Args&... args)
    {   
        auto* pos = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(stpcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), arg)) + 1;
        return ArgHandler<Args...>::insert(pos, args...);
    }   
};

// char array
template <size_t N, typename... Args>
struct ArgHandler<char[N], Args...>
{
    // strings
    static uint8_t* insert(uint8_t* buff, const char (&arg)[N], const Args&... args)
    {   
        auto* pos = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(stpcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff), &arg[0])) + 1;
        return ArgHandler<Args...>::insert(pos, args...);
    }   
};

// after last arg, end recursion
template <>
struct ArgHandler<>
{
    static uint8_t* insert(uint8_t* buff)
    {   
        return buff;
    }   
};

template <typename... Args>
void insertArgs(uint8_t* buff, const Args&... args)
{
    ArgHandler<Args...>::insert(buff, args...);
}
```

If I create a char ptr on the stack of a function and then pass it to my buffer-insertion code, everything works. However, in the same code if I pass the argument of the calling function directly into the buffer-insertion function, the compiler resolves to the wrong specialization (specifically the "literal types" specialization).

```
// works
void someFunction(const char* str)
{
    uint8_t buff[1024];
    const char* local_str = str;
    insertArgs(buff, local_str);
}

// resolves to incorrect specialization
void someFunction(const char* str)
{
    uint8_t buff[1024];
    insertArgs(buff, str);
}
```

I suspect this has to do with my lack of understanding of lvalue, rvalue, etc. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The code works exactly as you coded it, why are you saying it is incorrect? You have a specialization for character arrays, and when you call your template with character array, this specialization is chosen. This is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Your code appears to work for me, resolving to the right specialization with both versions of `someFunction`: https://www.ideone.com/dbbn04 -- what compiler are you using?

Comment: i'm consistently failing to compile, gcc 8.1.1; will post the exact gcc output soon...

Comment: ok, so the only way to catch this issue at compile time is with a static_assert, which I added to the "typename T" specialization to check if the argument is integral. I do hit the assertion with my char ptr case:

/home/miles/development/trader/src/logging/text_logger.h:94:19: error: static assertion failed: TextLogger: caught non-integral type
     static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "TextLogger: caught non-integral type");
                   ^~~

However, creating a stack pointer and assigning it to the fcn argument like my original example compiles fine.

Comment: This code works for me too. They select the same overload. Try the build command `g++ -std=c++1z main.cpp -o main`

Comment: [Demo](https://www.ideone.com/AmukzU) which uses the char array overload.